# linear form on the polynomials vector space satisfying $\phi(1) \ne 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\phi$ be a non zero linear form on $\mathbb{K}_n[X]$.

Can one assert that $\phi({1}) \ne 0$

where $1$ is the constant unitary polynomial ?

**The context is the following :**

Let $\phi$ be a linear form on $\mathbb{K}_n[X]$ such that

$$\phi((X-a)P) = 0$$

for any $P$ in $\mathbb{K}_{n-1}[x]$

It is asked to prove that there existts an element $\lambda \in \mathbb{K}$ such that $\phi = \lambda .P(a)$ for all $P \in \mathbb{K}_n[X]$

Comment: No, $\lambda = \phi(1)$ can be anything

Comment: Ok here is my approach to solve the actual question
Let $\psi$ be the linear form defined by $\psi(P) = P(a)$
The question asks to prove that $\phi$ and $\psi$ are proportional.
It suffices to prove that they have the same kernel.
it is clear that $\ker \psi \subset \ker \phi $ 
To prove that $\ker \phi \subset \ker \psi $ let $Q$ such that $\phi(Q) = 0$
Eucliden division of $Q$ by $X-a$ gives $\phi(Q) = \phi(Q(a))=0$
how to draw from this that $Q(a) = 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

By the division algorithm
$$P= (X-a)\cdot Q + P(a)$$
so $$\phi(P) = \phi( (X-a) Q) + P(a) \phi(1)= P(a) \phi(1) = \lambda P(a)$$

Answer (score 1):

No, one cannot assert that $\phi(1)\ne 0$.

A simple counterexample is $\phi(P) = P(1)-P(0)$. This is easily checked to be a linear form. And it is non-zero, because e.g. $\phi(x) = 1 - 0 = 1$.

But $\phi(1) = 1 - 1 = 0$.